# Get relevant posts from user input

Tags: c#, sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

I'm writing a customer support website where the user can submit questions. I want the user to see a list of relevant questions based on his input (title and post). It's will be very similar to what this site has (Similar questions).

I'm kind of stuck and not sure where to start. Any guidance on how to build this feature?

Comment: What have you tried so far? I would imagine that you should give "similarity points" for stuff, like 100 points for exact match of strings, and 20 points for every three consecutive words that match, 10 for every two, and 5 for every word that exists in both strings, etc... Something with that idea.

Comment: @Yorye I thought of something like that but a post can have hundreds of words it would take a long time to run a query for each of them. Unless there's a more efficient way to do that?

Comment: Maybe some quirky combination with Hoffman tree?

Comment: it should show relevant posts before entering any tags just like on this site

Comment: Take the top `X` words that appear most, in order, and match to other posts' top words, giving smaller indices match a bigger value. If it passes a certain threshold, mark it as relevant.

Answer (score 2):

As far as search on database is concerned you can use full text search

for more information, visit these links:

- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-IN/library/ms142571.aspx
- http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2008/09/05/sql-server-creating-full-text-catalog-and-index

Answer (score 1):

Lucene has a nice way to do things like this there is even one operator called [MoreLikeThis](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/MoreLikeThis) and rank and score, that can help you with what you want.

Luncene has a very nice port to .net [Lucenenet](http://lucenenet.apache.org/) that you can get with nuget